# Difficult Countexample Construction

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a nonnegative continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for every $\epsilon\in[0,1)$ that one had $\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}; n\to \infty} f(\epsilon+n)=0$. Give an example of a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't think this is true. If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = c$ with $c>0$. Then $f(\epsilon + n)>c/2>0$ for every $n\geq N$

Comment: I got that part. The question is whether the limit needs to exist. This appears here as Exercise 4. https://www.math.upenn.edu/~vedranso/Practice1.pdf

Comment: Oh I see. The wording is a little unclear. So the limit can not exist then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Help to visualize counter example**

The idea is given by Tsemo Aristide. I have plotted a different but similar function. Maybe it helps to understand what is going on.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider  $f$ defined on $R$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $[0,1]$ is $0$, if $n>0$,the restriction of $f$ to $[n,n+1]$ is defined by

$f(x)=0$ if 
$x\in [n,n+{1\over{n+1}}], x\in [n+{1\over n}, n+1]$,

The restriction of $f$ to $[n+{1\over{n+1}},n+{1\over n}]$ is a cut off function $g$ such that: if $a_n=n+{1\over{n+1}}$ and $b_n=n+{1\over{n}}$ $g(a_n)=g(b_n)=0$ and $g({{a_n+b_n}\over 2})=1$.

Comment: Ops. You're right. I'm sorry about that. Comment deleted.

Comment: What is the cutoff function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: See the second answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618981/cutoff-function-vs-mollifiers

Comment: It doesn't have to be mollifier, a piecewise linear function is also sufficient

Comment: You can also define a function $g:[a_n,b_n]$ such that the restriction of $g$ to $[a_n,{{a_n+b_n}\over 2}]$ is an affine function $h_1$ such that $h_1(a_n)=0, h_2({{a_n+b_n}\over 2})=1$ and the restriction of $g$ to $[{{a_n+b_n}\over 2},b_n]$ is an affine function $h_2$ such that $h_2({{a_n+b_n}\over 2})=1, h_2(b_n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Same spirit as Tsemo's answer: You may define for $x=n+t$, $n\in {\Bbb N}$ and $0\leq t<1$:
$$ f(n+t)=nt^n(1-t)$$
One has for any fixed $t$: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n+t)=0$ but $f(n/(n+1))=(n/(n+1))^{n+1}\rightarrow e^{-1}$.